# How to get rid of value 'None' after printing a fucntion with the Try and Except block

Tags: python-3.x

I've written a function like the following, it's pretty self-explaining and i can't properly summarize my task. So, the problem here is that my Try and Except block keep producing value 'None', which really screw me up in my next task when i tried to put it in an array and covnert it into a numpy array. Data_dict is a dictionary contains every attribute (as keys) of a data file i'm working on in this task.

TLDR: how can i stop the try and except block from producing value "None" or is there another way to execute my task.

I'm just 4 weeks into python and have no previous coding experience. Also, i'm using Jupyter Notebook. I've tried to add another Else block to get rid of the value but it just became worse.

```py
import datetime  
def compute_opening_duration(opening_time, closing_time):  
    #Input: two string: opening_time and closing_time  
    #Output: the opening duration in hours  
    #Return -1 if any time is in incorrect form.  
    str_format = "%H:%M:%S"  
    try:  
        a = datetime.datetime.strptime(closing_time, str_format) - datetime.datetime.strptime(opening_time, str_format)  
        print(a.total_seconds()/3600)   
    except ValueError:  
        print(-1) 

print(compute_opening_duration('5:30:00', '16:00:00'))  

#my 2nd task is to compile all the values of that function above and then put it an array
#then convert that into a numpy array and print out first 10 entries

a = list(compute_opening_duration(data_dict['Open'][i], data_dict['Close'][i]) for i in range (len(data_dict['Open'])))
a_numpyarray = np.asarray(a)

print(a_numpyarray[0:11])
```

i expected it to be numbers

but the actual output is: [None None None None None None None None None None None]

Comment: What is data_dict ? it is not defined in your code.

Comment: oh, it's a dictionary. it contains every key from the data file that i'm working on

Comment: I'll edit my post again :")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import datetime  
import numpy as np
def compute_opening_duration(opening_time, closing_time):  
    #Input: two string: opening_time and closing_time  
    #Output: the opening duration in hours  
    #Return -1 if any time is in incorrect form.  
    str_format = "%H:%M:%S"  
    try:  
        a = datetime.datetime.strptime(closing_time, str_format) - datetime.datetime.strptime(opening_time, str_format)  
        return a.total_seconds()/3600 
    except ValueError:  
        return -1 

# print(compute_opening_duration('5:30:00', '16:00:00'))  

#my 2nd task is to compile all the values of that function above and then put it an array
#then convert that into a numpy array and print out first 10 entries
data_dict={
    "Open" :['5:30:00'],
    "Close": ['16:00:00']
}
a = list(compute_opening_duration(data_dict['Open'][i], data_dict['Close'][i]) for i in range (len(data_dict['Open'])))
a_numpyarray = np.asarray(a)

print(a_numpyarray[0:11]) #[10.5]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for answering, i've tried to use Return to but it still didn't work. I've just edited my post to clarify my purpose of asking.

Comment: I've just clarify (again, ikr fml) data_dict in my hopefully last edit. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Your function doesn't have a return statement so by default it returns **None**, that's why you got 'None' value in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Remove print from the last line. Just keep this :

```
compute_opening_duration('5:30:00', '16:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering J.K. But i did goof and didn't ask clearly so this was all my bad. I've just edited it to clarify things up.